# How to center first node in Forest diagram

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nodes, forest

I want to horizontally center the first node Sing(f)=V(x,y,z). Everything I've tried so far won't work but frankly I don't know that much about Forest.

My Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  my edge label/.style={
if={greater(n(),n_children("!u")/2)}{
  if={equal(n(),int((n_children("!u")+1)/2))}{
    edge label={node [pos=.6] {#1}},
  }{
    edge label={node [pos=.4, right] {#1}},
  },
}{
  edge label={node [pos=.4, left] {#1}}
},
  },
  for tree={
inner sep=1pt,
text centered,
align=center,
font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
edge={font=\tiny},
if n children=3{calign=child, calign child=2}{},
s sep+=5pt,
l sep+=15pt,
  }
  [{$Sing(f)=V(x,y,z)$}
[{$Sing(f_x)=V(x,y_1)$}
  [{$Sing(f_{xx})=V(x,y_2,z_1)$}
    [{$Sing(f_{xxx})=V(x,y_3,z_2)$}
      [{$Sing(f_{xxxx})=V(x,y_4,z_3)$}
    [{$Sing(f_{xxxxx})=V(x,y_5,z_4)$}]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxxxy_4})=\emptyset$}]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxxxz_3})=V(x_1,y_5,z_3)$}]]
      [{$Sing(f_{xxxy_3})=\emptyset$}]
      [{$Sing(f_{xxxz_2})=V(x_1,y_4,z_2)$}]]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxy_2})=\emptyset$}]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxz_1})=\emptyset$}]]
  [{$Sing(f_{xy_1})=\emptyset$}]]
[{$Sing(f_y)=\emptyset$},fit=band]
[{$Sing(f_z)=V(y_1,z)$}
  [{$Sing(f_{zy_1})=\emptyset$}]
  [{$Sing(f_{zz})=\emptyset$}]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

I would be very grateful for any help and hints!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can understand your need, but you need A3 paper, not A4. Already in this form the tree doesn't fit A4 paper (with 1in margin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that the style you define for `edge label`s is never used, so I've omitted it from the examples in this answer. Similarly for `edge=\tiny` and `text centered`.*

I'm not sure what you mean by centring - centred with respect to what? If the page, the tree as a whole will be very lop-sided.

If you want to centre the tree and fit it on the page, however, you can always lie about its width. You must, however, be very careful with this as TeX will not then warn you if material flows off the page completely.

Here's the kind of output I'm thinking you might want:

[image: tree on page]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\makebox[0pt]{%
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    inner sep=1pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
    if n children=3{calign=child, calign child=2}{},
    s sep+=5pt,
    l sep+=15pt,
  }
  [{$Sing(f)=V(x,y,z)$}
[{$Sing(f_x)=V(x,y_1)$}
  [{$Sing(f_{xx})=V(x,y_2,z_1)$}
    [{$Sing(f_{xxx})=V(x,y_3,z_2)$}
      [{$Sing(f_{xxxx})=V(x,y_4,z_3)$}
    [{$Sing(f_{xxxxx})=V(x,y_5,z_4)$}]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxxxy_4})=\emptyset$}]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxxxz_3})=V(x_1,y_5,z_3)$}]]
      [{$Sing(f_{xxxy_3})=\emptyset$}]
      [{$Sing(f_{xxxz_2})=V(x_1,y_4,z_2)$}]]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxy_2})=\emptyset$}]
    [{$Sing(f_{xxz_1})=\emptyset$}]]
  [{$Sing(f_{xy_1})=\emptyset$}]]
[{$Sing(f_y)=\emptyset$},fit=band]
[{$Sing(f_z)=V(y_1,z)$}
  [{$Sing(f_{zy_1})=\emptyset$}]
  [{$Sing(f_{zz})=\emptyset$}]]]
\end{forest}}\par}
\end{document}
```

Note that this doesn't have anything specific to do with `forest`: the tree is just too wide for the page. Any too-big thing would present a similar problem ;).

## EDIT

Another option for fitting the tree onto the page is to rethink its structure. There are a couple of possibilities. One is to alter the internal structure of the nodes to make them split across 2 lines:

[image: altering internal structure of nodes]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\areaset{240mm}{152mm}% allow roughly the same total area for margins as you'd get with 1in margins, but let KOMA do the dividing and laying out of the page
\usepackage{array,forest}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    inner sep=1pt,
    align={@{}>{$}c<{$}@{}},
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
    if n children=3{calign=child, calign child=2}{},
    s sep+=5pt,
    l sep+=15pt,
  }
  [{Sing(f)\\=V(x,y,z)}
    [{Sing(f_x)\\=V(x,y_1)}
      [{Sing(f_{xx})\\=V(x,y_2,z_1)}
        [{Sing(f_{xxx})\\=V(x,y_3,z_2)}
          [{Sing(f_{xxxx})\\=V(x,y_4,z_3)}
            [{Sing(f_{xxxxx})\\=V(x,y_5,z_4)}]
            [{Sing(f_{xxxxy_4})\\=\emptyset}]
            [{Sing(f_{xxxxz_3})\\=V(x_1,y_5,z_3)}]
          ]
          [{Sing(f_{xxxy_3})\\=\emptyset}]
          [{Sing(f_{xxxz_2})\\=V(x_1,y_4,z_2)}]
        ]
        [{Sing(f_{xxy_2})\\=\emptyset}]
        [{Sing(f_{xxz_1})\\=\emptyset}]
      ]
      [{Sing(f_{xy_1})\\=\emptyset}]
    ]
    [{Sing(f_y)\\=\emptyset},fit=band]
    [{Sing(f_z)\\=V(y_1,z)}
      [{Sing(f_{zy_1})\\=\emptyset}]
      [{Sing(f_{zz})\\=\emptyset}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}\par}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could leave the internal node structure intact and restructure the relationship between the nodes. For example:

[image: restructured relationships between nodes within tree]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\areaset{240mm}{152mm}% allow roughly the same total area for margins as you'd get with 1in margins, but let KOMA do the dividing and laying out of the page
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    math content,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
    if n children=3{calign=child, calign child=2}{},
    s sep+=5pt,
    l sep+=5pt,
    if={level>2}{
      if n=1{
        l+=20pt
      }{
        if n'=1{
          l+=20pt
        }{
          if n children=0{
            append={[,phantom]}
          }{}
        }
      },
    }{
    },
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
  }
  [{Sing(f)=V(x,y,z)}
    [{Sing(f_x)=V(x,y_1)}
      [{Sing(f_{xx})=V(x,y_2,z_1)}
        [{Sing(f_{xxx})=V(x,y_3,z_2)}
          [{Sing(f_{xxxx})=V(x,y_4,z_3)}
            [{Sing(f_{xxxxx})=V(x,y_5,z_4)}]
            [{Sing(f_{xxxxy_4})=\emptyset}]
            [{Sing(f_{xxxxz_3})=V(x_1,y_5,z_3)}]
          ]
          [{Sing(f_{xxxy_3})=\emptyset}]
          [{Sing(f_{xxxz_2})=V(x_1,y_4,z_2)}]
        ]
        [{Sing(f_{xxy_2})=\emptyset}]
        [{Sing(f_{xxz_1})=\emptyset}]
      ]
      [{Sing(f_{xy_1})=\emptyset}]
    ]
    [{Sing(f_y)=\emptyset}]%,fit=band]
    [{Sing(f_z)=V(y_1,z)}
      [{Sing(f_{zy_1})=\emptyset}]
      [{Sing(f_{zz})=\emptyset}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}\par}
\end{document}
```

Whether any of this counts as centring the root node with respect to anything at all... that's another question.